# Stuck on an equation with extended Euclidean algorithm

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have an equation like this:

$$64r+102s=2$$

And so, using the extended Euclidean algorithm, I did such calculations:

$$102=64⋅1+38 \\
64=38⋅1+26\\
38=26⋅1+12\\
26=12⋅2+2\\
12=2⋅6+0
$$

Which led me to:

$$0=12-2⋅6=12-6⋅(26-12⋅2)=13⋅12-6⋅26=13⋅(38-26)-6⋅26=13⋅38-19⋅26=13⋅38-19⋅(64-38)= 32⋅38-19⋅64=32⋅(102-64)-19⋅64= -51⋅64+32⋅102$$

And here's when I get stuck. I can't find an error anywhere in the last part while it would imply that $r=-51\cdot\frac{2}{2}-\frac{102}{2}m=-51-51m$ which is not the correct answer. Could someone please tell where did I make a mistake?

Comment: You’re trying to express $2$ as an integer combination of $102$ and $64$, so you should start with $2=26-12\cdot6$, not with the bottom line.

Comment: Oh my God, what a stupid mistake. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You’re welcome! (I didn’t see your comment until after I converted mine to an answer.)

Comment: It is much easier to use [this method for the extended Euclidean algorithm,](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/23500) which completely eliminates the messy, painful, error-prone back-substitution process.

Comment: Thanks, will surely read on it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started in the wrong place. You want to express $2$ as an integer combination of $64$ and $102$, not $0$, so you should start with $2=26-2\cdot12$:

$$\begin{align*}
2&=26-2\cdot12\\
&=26-2(38-26)\\
&=3\cdot26-2\cdot38\\
&=3(64-38)-2\cdot38\\
&=3\cdot64-5\cdot38\\
&=3\cdot64-5(102-64)\\
&=8\cdot64-5\cdot102
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

There is a way that is less error-prone, and it uses tables

<kbd>Index $i$</kbd><kbd>Quotient $q_{i-1}$</kbd>      <kbd>Remainder $r_i$</kbd>         <kbd>$x_i$</kbd>                 <kbd>$y_i$</kbd>                   
<kbd>$0$</kbd>                         <kbd>$102$</kbd>                 <kbd>$1$</kbd>                 <kbd>$0$</kbd>                    
<kbd>$1$</kbd>                         <kbd>$64$</kbd>                  <kbd>$0$</kbd>                 <kbd>$1$</kbd>                    
<kbd>$2$</kbd>      <kbd>$102\div64=1$</kbd>       <kbd>$102-64=38$</kbd>      <kbd>$1-1\times0=1$</kbd>      <kbd>$0-1\times1=-1$</kbd>      
<kbd>$3$</kbd>      <kbd>$64\div38=1$</kbd>        <kbd>$64-38=26$</kbd>       <kbd>$0-1\times1=-1$</kbd>    <kbd>$1-1\times-1=2$</kbd>       
<kbd>$4$</kbd>      <kbd>$38\div26=1$</kbd>        <kbd>$38-26=12$</kbd>       <kbd>$1-1\times-1=2$</kbd>    <kbd>$-1-1\times2=-3$</kbd>     
<kbd>$5$</kbd>      <kbd>$26\div12=2$</kbd>        <kbd>$26-2\times12=2$</kbd>    <kbd>$-1-2\times2=-5$</kbd>   <kbd>$2-2\times-3=8$</kbd>       
<kbd>$6$</kbd>      <kbd>$12\div2=6$</kbd>         <kbd>$12-6\times2=0$</kbd>     <kbd>$2-6\times-5=32$</kbd>    <kbd>$-3-6\times8=-51$</kbd>

Where it can easily be seen that $\gcd(102,64)=2$ which is the last non-zero remainder and $-5\times102+8\times64=2$.

If you want to find all solutions of this Linear Diophantine Equation, then use the following formula: $r=r_0-51n$ and $s=s_0+32n$. That is, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and where $r_0=8$ $s_0=-5$

Side note: if you "factor" this equation, you get $32r+51s=1$, then:

$8\times32\equiv1\pmod{51}$

$256\equiv1\pmod{51}$

In fact, $256=5\times51+1$

EDIT: THE SECOND MODULAR MULTIPLICATIVE INVERSE:

$-5\times51\equiv1\pmod{32}$

This can be thought of as:

$-255\equiv-31\pmod{32}$

Adding $32$ is the same as not doing anything at all when working in $\mathbb{Z}_{32}$ and therefore

$-255\equiv1\pmod{32}$

Another way to think about this is $-255-1\equiv0\pmod{32}$, which implies

$-256\equiv0\pmod{32}$

In fact, $-256=32\times-8$

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh my god, I cannot believe how bad my answer looks in Internet Explorer 11 under Windows 8.1, having used Firefox in Ubuntu to make my answer and looks perfect! Damn you, StackExchange.